# Posting File to Spring Integration Using HTTP Inbound adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I am looking for a suggestion for a good technique to POST a file into a spring integration queue and then split it line by line for further processing.  The trick is that file could be quite large and I don't want to read it into memory.

I am looking at using the HTTP inbound adapter with POST but I am unsure of how to get the payload to the integration flow without reading the entire thing first.

Currently I am using an MVC controller, saving it to a temp file and reading it line by line before passing each line onto a gateway.  Would like to do this entirely in spring integration if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the standard adapter for this.

Probably the easiest way to implement would be a custom controller that streams the lines into the SI flow as messages using a [messaging gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway).

Comment: Which is exactly what I am doing already,   Validation that I am taking a reasonable approach is always good.

Comment: `> saving it to a temp file` - Perhaps you can read directly from the input stream and send each line to the gw (avoiding the IO to the file system).

Answer (score 0):

The `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` supports `message-converters` to inject. And one of them can be `MultipartAwareFormHttpMessageConverter` which you can inject with the `MultipartFileReader` implementation. That one can return `MultipartFile#getInputStream()`.

The last one can be used from the `FileSplitter` which is available since Spring Integration `4.1` to read the stream line by line.